# Hazelcast EntryProcessor executes on all nodes

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using an embeded version of Hazelcast 5.2.1 and I noticed that EntryProcessor executes on all cluster members.

In my entry processor, I have a logic which fetch some data from database (based on the data definition in the distributed map) and send the result into a bus. The problem is that I receive twice the same notification since the both cluster members execute the task.

Why the entry proccessor executes on both cluster members?

Is there a way to force the execution to only the key owner or at least that the entry processor is executed only once?

My entry processor definition:

```
public class myEntryProcessor implements EntryProcessor<String, SerializableSession, Void>, Offloadable, IdentifiedDataSerializable
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: It might be the case that the entry processor is executed on the key owner, and the backup entry processor (the one returned from the getBackupProcessor method) is executed on the backup, which is the other member. Can you check if this is the case here by overriding the getBackupProcessor method?

Comment: Indeed, when I override the getBackupProcessor processor (just return null) the entry processor executes only on one node so it works as I expected. But in this case, the backup stored on other node will be never updated with a new value? Is it possible to execute the entry processor only by one node and keep the backups up to date ?

Comment: OK, I think I got it. So it means that I will have to implement a custom backup processor which will only modify the stored data with the new value without any other action. Thanks for help

Comment: Yes indeed. That would be the ideal solution